# How to Resolve Service Registered in ConfigureService and use in Autofac ConfigureContainer method in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, autofac, .net-core-3.0

My challenge here is to resolve `IHttpContextAccessor` service I registered in `ConfigureServices` method, and use it to register an instance with Autofac on the `ConfigureContainer` method. But with the new way of using Autofac in .net core 3.0, I'm finding it really challenge to do so. The method I tried was the following;

```
        public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            var container = builder.Build();

            var httpContextAccessor = container.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var executionContextAccessor = new ExecutionContextAccessor(httpContextAccessor);

            ServicesAutofacExtensions.RegisterServicesWithAutofac(executionContextAccessor, Configuration, _loggerForApi);
        }
```

But it throws this error when I run

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
>   services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
>   Build() or Update() can only be called once on a ContainerBuilder.

Now I know in the docs, it says that the ContainerBuilder should not be built in this method that the factory takes care of this automatically. But how do I then resolve the IHttpContextAccessor to use it in the ConfigureContainer?
I have searched and researched on possible solutions but found none. Please help.

Comment: May be it is better to use lambda expressions to register, e.g. like this https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#lambda-expression-components

Here in expression you will receive instance of container and I'll be able to resolve required service and pass it as parameter.

Comment: What  `ServicesAutofacExtensions.RegisterServicesWithAutofac` is doing ? Why do you need  to resolve `IHttpContextAccessor` here ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand `ServicesAutofacExtensions.RegisterServicesWithAutofac` is where I'm adding my appilication services and classes to the DI Container. Among those is a class `ExecutionContextAccessor` that accepts `IHttpContextAccessor` in its constructor. That is why I need to resolve it in order to register `ExecutionContextAccessor` as an Instance. I don't know if I made myself clear enough

Comment: @KaceyEzerioha I question the current design choice. The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. It would be awesome if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do?

Comment: @KaceyEzerioha it is not the way Dependency Injection works. When you register things, you register all the components without having to create any. Then the DI framework will create the dependency graph.